# How to Return to an Earlier State of a Document

Tags: texshop

Recently, I have lost a great amount of work on a project in LaTeX because of unwittingly saving changes when cutting out a large chunk of text and copying the remaining part. I was wondering if there was any way to bring back a version of a LaTeX document from a previous time to this incident. I know such a function is available on Google Docs, but is it available here? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that would depend in part on your editor but I'm not really clear what you mean by 'here'. LaTeX just compiles a file on your disk. It doesn't know anything about the history of that file. By far the best solution is to use a version control system such as subversion or git or similar. You can keep your repository of files on you hard disk (hopefully backed up somewhere else!) so you can work without an internet connection, including committing changes. This takes a little getting used to but is well worth it. There is a really good introductory article somewhere which enabled me to...

Comment: do this even though I had failed to understand anything else I'd read and even though it was focused on Windows (go figure). It explained how to set up the repo and use `svn-multi`. I'll try to find it if you are interested.

Comment: By here, I mean for LaTeX. And, if this helps, I still have the old pdf file from the completed file. I haven't recompiled it yet in hopes that I can recover the files from the pdf. My LaTeX editor is TeXShop.

Comment: No. You cannot recover the source from the PDF except in the sense that you could copy and paste text back into TeXShop. If applicable, you can use the 'undo' feature of your editor. TeXShop may also have saved a backup of your original file, depending on how you configured it. (It is a while since I used it but I assume it still has this feature.) But if the backup is gone or if you configured it not to make one and it is too late to 'undo' then TeXShop won't help you. Sorry. The PDF is just like printing it except easier to copy-paste than using OCR.

Comment: Have you closed the file since the incident? Have you quit TeXShop since the incident? Do you have a backup of your important documents you could restore from? (Hint: You really should. Data you don't back up is data you are prepared to lose in an instant.)

Comment: Yes and yes. I don't have any form of backup. So I'm SOL. Therefore, I'm going to take this opportunity to create a backup. How do I do this for future use, so this catastrophe never happens again?

Comment: If back-up on a external device, e.g. USB stick, is possible, simply do that. `:)`

Comment: [Here](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-3/scharrer/scharrer.pdf) is the article I mentioned. I use an svn repository on my hard disk. That is then backed up using a (free) SpiderOak account. I also backup my entire hard disk once a week. (Once you've had a hard disk die, you don't think this is an optional luxury!) When I was on Mac OS X, I used Carbon Copy Cloner for this. (On GNU/Linux, I use rsync but OS X is more complex in terms of backup requirements.) If you use TeX, a subversion repository takes little space because you only version the source and only that is synced to the cloud.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg That is certainly much better than no backup but version control is better because it doesn't matter how long it is until you realise you screwed up and need to recover something from an earlier version!

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this as backup is not really on topic for this site but if you comment, I will still get notified and try to respond when I'm next on the site.

Comment: I just index the document with today's date in yymmdd format in the filename to avoid problems like these.

Comment: Actually, you will need to `@username` one of us for somebody to be notified now as there are more people involved ;).

Comment: @JPi That is not bad but it is more expensive in terms of disk space and less flexible than version control. It makes it harder to 'cherry-pick' changes, harder to manage multiple versions of a document efficiently, and harder to keep track of changes. That is, with your method, you have to do all the work yourself! I'm lazy, so I let version control do most of the work for me... Also, backup somewhere else (another disk, cloud, whatever) is essential whichever method you use.

Comment: everybody loves `git`. no exceptions. :)

Comment: I have my own virtual server for `subversion`. All important projects are in a subversion repo. In addition to the server I have most projects checked out regularly on several computers.

Comment: If you're using OS X 10.7 or later and a recent version of TeXShop, it will automatically save versions of your document. See Apple's documentation http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4753?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US and the TeXShop home page http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/aboutTeXShopAndLion2.html for more details.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, Dick Koch (the TeXShop developer) also gave a presentation that included a discussion of versioning at the TUG 2014 conference. See section 13 of his [preprint](https://tug.org/tug2014/booklet/koch/Tugboat-MacTeX-TeXShopDesign.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It's a lesson we all learn, make backups, lots of backups.

You can use external devices, hard disks or USB sticks, and copy manually, or set up a revision control system, GIT, and the like.

If you don't have the expertise to set up your own revision control system, you might want to consider using dropbox or similar. Many automatically store earlier versions of your document whenever you save. Of course that means you have to be okay with storing your information on their servers...